# table multiplication in C programming language

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;
    printf("Enter the number you want multiplication table of:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("multiplication table of %d is as follow:\n", num);

    //printf("%d X 1 = %d\n", num, num * 1);
    //printf("%d X 2 = %d\n", num, num * 2);
    //printf("%d X 3 = %d\n", num, num * 3);
    //printf("%d X 4 = %d\n", num, num * 4);
    //printf("%d X 5 = %d\n", num, num * 5);
    //printf("%d X 6 = %d\n", num, num * 6);
    //printf("%d X 7 = %d\n", num, num * 7);
    //printf("%d X 8 = %d\n", num, num * 8);
    //printf("%d X 9 = %d\n", num, num * 9);
    //printf("%d X 10 = %d\n", num, num * 10);
    //printf("%d X 11 = %d\n", num, num * 11);
    //printf("%d X 12 = %d\n", num, num * 12);
    //printf("%d X 13 = %d\n", num, num * 13);
    //printf("%d X 14 = %d\n", num, num * 14);
    //printf("%d X 15 = %d\n", num, num * 15);
    //printf("%d X 16 = %d\n", num, num * 16);
    //printf("%d X 17 = %d\n", num, num * 17);
    //printf("%d X 18 = %d\n", num, num * 18);
    //printf("%d X 19 = %d\n", num, num * 19);
    //printf("%d X 20 = %d\n", num, num * 20);

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        printf("%d X %d = %d\n", num, i, num * i);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

I need a quick answer.

I am facing a problem in the table multiplication in C. And I have been stuck in it. I'm expecting that I will get the answer of the this problem.

Comment: You might get an answer if you ask a question. What is the problem exactly? The code looks good to me.

Comment: Seems you forgot to ask a question

Comment: FWIW, this isn't what [*multiplication table*](https://www.mathsisfun.com/tables.html) means in American English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop you wrote is a good approach at simplifying the commented code.
It you want the full table, you should run the loop from `i = 1` to `i <= 20`. You should also check the return value of `scanf()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;

    printf("Enter the number you want multiplication table of:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("multiplication table of %d is as follows:\n", num);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        printf("%d X %d = %d\n", num, i, num * i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```